# How to set all 50 states to a country code as 'US'

Tags: mysql, charts, google-visualization

Okay so I'm using Google Charts API to create a map that displays sales based on location. Some code in my chart are countries so France is displayed in my CSV file as `FR`. However, the API ONLY does `Countries` so my data in the file that are states such as `NC`, `CA`, `NY` etc... need to be stored as `US`. Would a case statement for each state be the best way to go?

```
States        I need these states to be set equal to 'US'
StateID
-------
AL
CA
HI
NY
etc...
```

Comment: Show us sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Hi, we need table and data samples and what did you do already?

Comment: $result = $conn->query("SELECT CUST_STATE_CD,
CASE WHEN CUST_STATE_CD  = 'AK', 'AZ','AR', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DE', 'DC', 'FL', 'GA','HI','ID', 'IL','IN', 'IA', 'KS','KY', 'LA', 'ME','MD', 'MA', 'MI', 'MN','MS', 'MO', 'MT', 'NE', 'NV', 'NH', 'NJ', 'NM','NY', 'NC', 'ND','OH','OK', 'OR', 'PA', 'PR','RI', 'SC','SD', 'TN', 'TX', 'UT', 'VT', 'VA', 'WA', 'WV','WI', ‘WY'
 THEN 'US'
    count(CUST_NM) as totalCust  from sales_filev1 GROUP BY CUST_STATE_CD");

Comment: are you using `google.visualization.GeoChart` or `google.visualization.Map` -?- any code would help...

Comment: .geochart      $result = $conn->query("SELECT CUST_STATE_CD, count(CUST_NM) as totalCust  

  from sales_filev1 GROUP BY CUST_STATE_CD");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this sql...

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN
    CUST_STATE_CD in ('AK', 'AZ', 'AR', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DE', 'DC', 'FL', 'GA', 'HI', 'ID', 'IL', 'IN', 'IA', 'KS', 'KY', 'LA', 'ME', 'MD', 'MA', 'MI', 'MN', 'MS', 'MO', 'MT', 'NE', 'NV', 'NH', 'NJ', 'NM', 'NY', 'NC', 'ND', 'OH', 'OK', 'OR', 'PA', 'PR', 'RI', 'SC', 'SD', 'TN', 'TX', 'UT', 'VT', 'VA', 'WA', 'WV', 'WI', 'WY')
  THEN
    'US'
  ELSE
    CUST_STATE_CD
  END as state,
  count(CUST_NM) as totalCust
FROM
  sales_filev1
GROUP BY
  CASE WHEN
    CUST_STATE_CD in ('AK', 'AZ', 'AR', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DE', 'DC', 'FL', 'GA', 'HI', 'ID', 'IL', 'IN', 'IA', 'KS', 'KY', 'LA', 'ME', 'MD', 'MA', 'MI', 'MN', 'MS', 'MO', 'MT', 'NE', 'NV', 'NH', 'NJ', 'NM', 'NY', 'NC', 'ND', 'OH', 'OK', 'OR', 'PA', 'PR', 'RI', 'SC', 'SD', 'TN', 'TX', 'UT', 'VT', 'VA', 'WA', 'WV', 'WI', 'WY')
  THEN
    'US'
  ELSE
    CUST_STATE_CD
  END
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!